# GLSL Compatibility Issues

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, lwjgl

I've been working on a project on my laptop using lwjgl with GLSL 1.3. My shaders compile fine on my laptop however, when trying to compile the same shader on my desktop which has a newer graphics card I get an error stating that the shader could not compile because there was an error in the shader. But, the shader log doesn't output any errors. I thought that GLSL what backwards compatible with its self.

```
GL11.glGetString(GL20.GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION);
```

returns

```
3.30 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
```

Which I'm assuming is the same as the standard GLSL 3.30.  Here is an example vert and frag shader that works on my laptop and not my desktop.

basic_color.vert

```
#version 130

uniform mat4 projection_matrix;
uniform mat4 modelview_matrix;

in vec3 a_Vertex;
in vec4 a_Color;
out vec4 color;

void main(void) 
{
    vec4 pos = modelview_matrix * vec4(a_Vertex, 1.0);
    gl_Position = projection_matrix * pos;  
    color = a_Color;
}
```

basic_color.frag

```
#version 130

in vec4 color;
out vec4 outColor;

void main(void) 
{
    outColor = color;   
}
```

Comment: "*But, the shader log doesn't output any errors.*" Are you checking *all* of the shader logs? The shader compilation logs *and* the program linking log?

Comment: I'm simply using glGetShaderInfoLog() which outputs: Could not compile the shaders, they are invalid. Could not compile shader: 5

Answer (score 0):

Try `#version 330 compatibility` or `#version 330` or use varying and gl_FragColor, gl_Position instead of in\out

Comment: How could pretending that his shader is a *higher* version than it is in any way help?

Comment: older version = more restrictions = more errors. Yes - Pretty naive but what if... :)